# reading .env file from node - env file is not published

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build, dotenv

I am trying to read .env file using "dotenv" package but it returns undefined from process.env.DB_HOST after published to gcloud run.  I see all files except for the .env file in root directory when I output all files to log.  I do have .env file in my project on a root directory.  Not sure why it's not getting pushed to gcloud or is it?. I do get a value when I tested locally for process.env.DB_HOST.

I used this command to publish to google run.
gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/my-project/test-api:1.0.0 .

Comment: Your env file should be ignored by git, which is why you don't see it - in production, you set the _actual environment variables_.

Comment: I just commented out .env out from .gitignore as you said and it worked.  thank you.  so I shouldn't add it on gitignore?  (I have secret password etc there)

Comment: **Don't do that.** The point is to keep your secrets _out_ of version control. Again, set _actual env vars_ in prod - dotenv is a _dev_ tool. https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv#faq

Comment: I am a little confused now.   so I added .env file on gitignore so it won't get added to version control.  I have a .sh file that generates .env file by getting secrets from gcloud secret manager before publishing the project.  Should I add it on the docker file or something to generate .env on the fly on gcloud instead?  Sorry, I am new to node and docker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you haven't a [`.gcloudignore`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/gcloudignore) file in your project, gcloud CLI use the `.gitignore` by default

Create a `.gcloudignore` and put the file that you don't want to upload when you use gcloud CLI command. So, don't put the `.env` in it!

---

**EDIT 1**

When you add a `.gcloudignore`, the gcloud CLI no longer read the `.gitignore` file and use it instead.

Therefore, you can define 2 different logics

- `.gitignore` list the file that you don't want to push to the repository. **Put the `.env` file in it** to NOT commit it
- `.gcloudignore` list the file that you don't want to send with the gcloud CLI. **DON'T put the `.env` file in it** to include it when you send your code with the gcloud CLI

Comment: I DO need to publish .env file to gcloud so I can read the env variables in the code but I don't want to commit it to source control.  that's why I added .env file to .gitignore but as you said it doesn't get published to gcloud if I add to that.  so how will .gcloudignore help?

Comment: @wil, I updated my answer to make it clearer. One file is for GIT the other for GCLOUD, you can define different file to exclude according to the command that you use.